# como lograr rango de 100 en 100?

Tags: python

Necesito escribir un procedimiento que almacene en un registro los datos de 10 alumnos, conteniendo su legajo (generado automáticamente de 100 en 100, comenzando con legajo = 1, para que quede ordenado), nombre, apellido y las calificaciones de los 3 exámenes parciales de una asignatura. Calcular el promedio de cada uno y mostrar el listado de alumnos junto con un mensaje de Promovido si el alumno supera o iguala el promedio de 7 , Regular si resulta entre 4 y 7 y Libre en caso que la nota media no alcance el 4.

no se donde poner el rango(for i in range(1,1001,100):) en mi codigo para que el legajo de los 10 alumnos quede asi:

[1,“Juan”, “Pérez”, 5,7,8]

[101,“Luis”, “García”, 2,8,8]

[201,“Maria”, “Alonso”, 6,6,10]

………………………………..

[901,“Alicia”, “Rojas”, 2,2,4]

el código que hice hasta ahora es este:

```
from pyrecord import Record
import random
import numpy as np

# Define el registro como tipo de datos
Nota = Record.create_type("Nota","legajo","nombre_apellido","nota1","nota2","nota3",legajo = 
0,nombre_apellido = '',nota1 = 0,nota2 = 0,nota3 = 0)


def cargar(vector,archivo):
    archivo = open(archivo, 'r')
    contador_de_lineas = 0
    for linea in archivo:
        vector[contador_de_lineas] = Nota()
        carga_aleatoria(vector[contador_de_lineas],linea.rstrip('\n'))
        contador_de_lineas += 1
    archivo.close
    return contador_de_lineas,vector


def carga_aleatoria(registro, nombre):
    registro.alumno = nombre
    registro.legajo = random.randrange(1,1001,100)
    registro.nota1 = random.randint(1,10)
    registro.nota2 = random.randint(1,10)
    registro.nota3 = random.randint(1,10)



def mostrar_registro(registro):
    print("[",registro.legajo,",",registro.alumno,",",registro.nota1,",",registro.nota2,",",registro.nota3,"]",)  


def mostrar_registro_2(registro,valor_adicional,valor_adicional1):
    print("Legajo : ",registro.legajo," |Nombre y apellido: ",registro.alumno," |"," Promedio: ",
    valor_adicional," |", " Condicion: ",valor_adicional1)


def ordenar_vector(vector,cantidad):
    se_hizo_un_cambio = True
    while se_hizo_un_cambio:
        se_hizo_un_cambio = False
        indice = 1
        while indice < cantidad:
            if vector[indice - 1].legajo > vector[indice].legajo:
                #swap 
                aux = vector[indice - 1]
                vector[indice - 1 ] = vector[indice]
                vector[indice] = aux
                se_hizo_un_cambio = True
            indice += 1
       
def mostrar_en_rango(vector,minimo,maximo,elementos,etiqueta):
    for n in range(elementos):
        promedio = (vector[n].nota1 + vector[n].nota2 + vector[n].nota3 ) / 3
        if (promedio >= minimo and promedio < maximo):
            mostrar_registro_2(vector[n],promedio,etiqueta)
    

def main():
    cantidad_maxima = 100
    cant_real = 0  

    # Define un vector de 100 elementos de tipo Nota pero vacio
    notas = np.empty([cantidad_maxima,], dtype=Nota)
    # Pedir que se cargue el vector con los datos del archivo
    cant_real,notas = cargar(notas,"alumnos.txt")


    ordenar_vector(notas,cant_real)

    # Mostrar el vector
    for i in range(cant_real):
        mostrar_registro(notas[i])

    mostrar_en_rango(notas,1,4,cant_real,"libre")

    mostrar_en_rango(notas,4,7,cant_real,"regular")

    mostrar_en_rango(notas,7,11,cant_real,"Promovido")



 main()
```

https://pastebin.com/pjhGQh6Y

Comment: Necesitamos un código "minimo" reproducible para entender el problema, no el programa/script completo. Hay muchos datos que no necesitamos saber y se pierde mucho tiempo analizandolo. Si puedes crear un ejemplo reducido de lo que necesitas, lo entenderemos mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría el enumerate para saber en qué iteración estamos, pasarlo al método carga_aleatoria que calculará de forma sencilla el legajo, no he podido probar el código pero creo que así funcionaría.

Ejemplo:

```
def cargar(vector,archivo):
    archivo = open(archivo, 'r')
    contador_de_lineas = 0
    for i, linea in enumerate(archivo):
        vector[contador_de_lineas] = Nota()
        carga_aleatoria(vector[contador_de_lineas],linea.rstrip('\n'), i)
        contador_de_lineas += 1
    archivo.close
    return contador_de_lineas,vector


def carga_aleatoria(registro, nombre, i):
    registro.alumno = nombre
    registro.legajo = 1 + (100 * i)
    registro.nota1 = random.randint(1,10)
    registro.nota2 = random.randint(1,10)
    registro.nota3 = random.randint(1,10)
```

Comment: esta perfecto funciona, hay algún otro modo sin usar el enumerate

Comment: @angel podrías crear una lista predeterminada con los número que deseas utilizar y ir cogiendo con el pop(), pero desde mi punto de  vista es algo feo. No se me ocurre una manera más óptima.